# Metro client hangs when calling WCF webserver with wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, jakarta-ee, wsdl, ntlm, java-metro-framework

I have generated a webservice client with a local wsdl using [Metro](http://metro.java.net/) 1.2 this way:

```
./wsimport.sh -extension -verbose -wsdllocation service.wsdl -s src -d target service.wsdl -Xendorsed
```

The wsdl uses `SOAP 1.2` and `wsHttpBinding`. It's supposed to connect to a WCF server that's using `NTLM` as authentication method.

I have created an `Authenticator` to handle the `NTLM` authentication:

```
public class NtlmAuthenticator extends Authenticator
{
    private String username = "";
    private String password = "";

    public NtlmAuthenticator(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password.toCharArray());
    }
}
```

Which I set before each webservice method is called:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService")
public ICustomerService getWSHttpBindingICustomerService() {
    ICustomerService service =
        super.getPort(new QName("http://xmlns.example.com/services/Customer",
                "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService"), ICustomerService.class);

    NtlmAuthenticator auth = new NtlmAuthenticator(username, password);  
    Authenticator.setDefault(auth);   

    return service;
}
```

If I use the wrong username/password, I get a `401 Unauthorized` back, which is well and all, but when I use the *correct* username/password, the call hangs and I never get a response!

The request looks like this (captured it with netcat, so host is different, and no https):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Content-type: application/soap+xml;charset="utf-8";action="http://xmlns.example.com/services/ICustomerService/GetCustomer"
Password: [password]
Authorization: Basic [auth]
Username: [username]
Accept: application/soap+xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2
User-Agent: JAX-WS RI 2.1.7-b01-
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Host: localhost:5500
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 603

[xml follows]
```

I have also tried with `wget 1.12` (heard that 1.11 had problem with NTLM), but it too never yields a response, just waits.

```
[...]
---request end---
[writing POST file customerRequest.xml ... done]
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

I've seen that [others](http://metro.1045641.n5.nabble.com/java-client-WCF-wshttpbinding-td1052793.html) have gotten this behaviour before, but I have not been able to find out why. Can anyone shed some light on this? JDK 1.6 on linux.

Comment: You know if the request arrives at your WCF app at all?

Comment: I don't know about the ones that hangs, I'm supposed to get the logs tomorrow for just that. I don't have control over the WCF server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I missed a line in my generated client code that enabled `Addressing` and pass it to the `getPort` super method:

```
WebServiceFeature wsAddressing = new AddressingFeature(true);

ICustomerService service =
    super.getPort(new QName("http://xmlns.example.com/services/Customer",
            "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService"), ICustomerService.class, 
            wsAddressing);
```

Why metro didn't generate this is beyond me. The method looked like this in the end:

```
@WebEndpoint(name = "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService")
public ICustomerService getWSHttpBindingICustomerService() {
    WebServiceFeature wsAddressing = new AddressingFeature(true);

    ICustomerService service =
        super.getPort(new QName("http://xmlns.example.com/services/Customer",
                "WSHttpBinding_ICustomerService"), ICustomerService.class, 
                wsAddressing);

    NtlmAuthenticator auth = new NtlmAuthenticator(username, password);  
    Authenticator.setDefault(auth);   

    return service;
}
```

This in turn added a SOAP header to the message:

```
<S:Header>
  <To xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">https://services.example.com/CustomerService.svc</To>
  <Action xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">http://xmlns.example.com/services/ICustomerService/GetCustomer</Action>
  <ReplyTo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
    <Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</Address>
  </ReplyTo>
  <MessageID xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">uuid:d33c2888-abfa-474d-8729-95d2bcd17a96</MessageID>
</S:Header>
```